# Find and remove regex string in Velocity

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, substring, velocity, live-templates

I've created a Live Template with IntelliJ IDEA and I'm trying to find and remove a specific `String` within Velocity through a `variable` but failed

I tried to set `$moduleName` variable through `$NAME` variable *-which is giving 'File name'-* with `RegExp`.

I'm removing `View` string (part of File name) during creating JS file, but failed. Code:

```
## Input for 'File Name' is FooView**

#set($regex = '/(View)/') ## Try to get 'View' string with regex**
#set($checkRegex = $NAME.matches($regex)) ## Checks if regex finds**
#set($moduleName = $NAME.replaceAll($regex, '')) ## Try to remove 'View' string on $NAME variable**

## So the results;**
$checkRegex ## Returns as FALSE**
$moduleName ## Still returns all input as 'FooView'**
```

Comment: Why not to just replace `View`? you want to replace string that ends with View?

Comment: @user7294900 Could you post any sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace View, put it *as is* in regex:

```
#set($regex = 'View')
```

Comment: I've already tried to state only string without `parenthesis` and `slash`es but did not work either! Still `matches()` returns as false and renders `$moduleName` as variable name.

Comment: @NuriEngin matches is search for a *match* and it's not relevant here, also use `$NAME.replace($regex, ''))` ,also are you sure parameter is a string and not a file?